# How to create a mesh fabric with ability to change color in color ramp procedurally?

Tags: materials, procedural

I am trying to create this mesh shoe fabric material in Blender procedurally and failing. After a 2hr attempt, the closest result I got is attached below. however, I want to achieve result like the photo attached.

Any suggestions on how it might be done?

My attempt:

[image: my attempt]

Goal:

[image: Goal]

Comment: Because of the very poor quality it's impossible to see the material in your provided reference image. Do you have any better images of what your goal is?

Comment: Connect the output of the second Voronoi Texture to the Height input of a Bump Node - connect that to the Normal of the BSDF. Turn the strength _way_ down.

Comment: Please give us more details ... your title is aiming to change color - for that, delete Colorramp node and plug Voronoi output to Mix node > Factor and set Colours you like ... but your reference (goal) image is not coloured at all and is more about displacement (bump or normal) - for that follow Christopher's comment (in that case Q-title should be changed to something more relevant).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett ... just a note - even Voronoi pattern appears to be smooth in this black&white texture, used by Normal generates very sharp edges ... so it is not going to result in smooth like gumy fabric.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://imgur.com/a/GKG8h34) ?

Comment: yes i want something like that. any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Really simple - forget the second Voronoi texture, and "soften" it's effect (heavily) with a Mix Color Node before going into the Height input of a Bump Node:

(Pardon the crude UV unwrap - just there to demonstrate the example)

[image: Bump]

To further mimic your example image, you can add "colored wear" and "dimples" by using an Ambient Occlusion node - experiment with both outputs to see what works best for you (as I am somewhat unclear of the end objective). Don't forget to enable Ambient Occlusion in the Render Properties panel (right side).

[image: AO]

Comment: Thanks!i did exactly as you suggest but my result is totally different https://imgur.com/a/VdJVCAs

Comment: Up the scale of the Voronoi texture a bit, and bring the "mix" on the Mix Color node up really high (I usually use .98 or.99 - procedural textures are _very_ strong - this makes it "milder"). Also, if you want the bumps to go "in" instead of "out", place an Invert Node between the Voronoi and the MixColor nodes. Also, notice that the Voronoi texture you used in your image still has the randomness set at 0.5 (not 0 like your first example).

Comment: the texture definitely got better however the mix(color) isn't really smoothening out the boxy nature of the Voronoi (I'm sure there is a better way to put it). I bumped up the scale to 250 and used the invert node as you suggested. I am not able to nail the texutre like your though.https://imgur.com/a/A3VwJJ6

Comment: You placed the invert node after the bump - it must be  in between the Voronoi and the MixColor node.